# Convert a parsed SAXParser output to a HashMap/any other data structure

Tags: xml, scala, data-structures, hashmap, saxparser

I am using SAXParser to parse any generic XML. Below is my code in Scala:-

```
object saxParser extends App {

  val y = new InputSource(new StringReader("<x><y name='jack'>a</y><y name='mary'>b</y></x>"))
  val factory: SAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
  val saxParser: SAXParser = factory.newSAXParser();
  val userhandler: UserHandler = new UserHandler();
  saxParser.parse(y, userhandler);

}


class UserHandler extends DefaultHandler {

  val y = false;
  val tagContentBuffer = new StringBuilder();
  var nodeName = "";

  override def startElement(uri: String, localName: String, qName: String, attributes: Attributes) = {

    println(qName);
    nodeName = qName;
    for (i <- 0 to attributes.getLength) {
      if (attributes.getQName(i) != null) {
        print(attributes.getQName(i) + " = ")
        println(attributes.getValue(i))
      }
    }

  }

  override def characters(ch: Array[Char], start: Int, length: Int) {

    tagContentBuffer.append(new String(ch, start, length))
    println(nodeName + " = " + tagContentBuffer)
    tagContentBuffer.setLength(0)

  }

  override def endElement(uri:String, localName:String, qName:String) {
      println(qName);
    }
}
```

So my output will be:-

```
x
y
name = jack
y = a
y
y
name = mary
y = b
y
x
```

Now instead of printing the output I want to store this data and return it to the user in the form of a HashMap or any other data structure. The problem is the input XML "y" can be anything. Here I am using a sample one but it will be a user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done by using a MultiHashMap of String,Any. Using MultiHashMap so that I can store duplicate keys that come in the XML.